# Showing high and low PC of every program functions using DWARF library

Tags: elf, dwarf

I am trying to make this code work : https://github.com/eliben/code-for-blog/blob/master/2011/dwarf_get_func_addr.c
It is extracted from a tutorial made by Eli Bendersky on http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information
Unfortunately, low pc and high pc return always the same address for almost every function:

```
DW_TAG_subprogram: 'aFunctionName'

low pc  : 0x00000001
high pc : 0x7f3a00000001
```

Whereas if objdump --dwarf=decodedline ./lulesh_normal >> dump_dwarf.txt
gives me :

```
File name                            Line number    Starting address
lulesh.cc                                   1297            0x402e00

lulesh.cc                                   1297            0x402e11
lulesh.cc                                   1299            0x402ee4
lulesh.cc                                   1300            0x402ef0
lulesh.cc                                   1301            0x402ef6
lulesh.cc                                   1299            0x402f00
[...]
```

So it manages to link line and address but not to find the real address of the functions.
Any idea why ?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in `dwarf_get_func_addr.c` has at least one bug: it assumes that every function has `DW_AT_low_pc` and `DW_AT_high_pc` attributes, and will print uninitialized values if that is not the case.

You should initialize `lowpc = highpc = -1;` on line 42, so as not to print unintialized values.

Other than that, it's impossible to help you without access to your `lulesh_normal` binary.

You should do `readelf -wi lulesh_normal`, and then step through `list_func_in_die` in a debugger, and compare what the program is reading there with the output from `readelf` -- they should match one to one. If they don't, your version of `libdwarf` is possibly buggy.